# Assembly programing bug

Tags: loops, assembly, type-conversion

I'm new at programming assembly. Now I'm trying to write a program that converts number from decimal to binary. But I got stuck with one program while trying to input. After i output msg2 and get into loop, program doesn't turn off. I can input a lot of numbers and program doesn't turn off. I guess problem is in convertnumber: cmp si,cx (si is how many numbers I have to input, cx- how many numbers I have already written), but I am not sure about that. Where have I made a mistake and how could I correct it?

```
 .MODEL small
 .Stack 100h

 .DATA
 msg0 db 'how many numbers will  include your input number(example. 123 is 3 numbers)? $'
 msg1 db 'Now input number from 0 to 65535: $'
 number db 255, ?, 256 dup ('$')
 numberinAscii db 255, ?, 256 dup ('$')
 enterbutton db 13,10,'$' 


 .CODE
 start:
mov ax, @data
mov ds,ax
mov ah,09h
mov dx, offset msg0 ; first message output
int 21h
xor ah,ah ; function 00h of

int 16h ; int 16h gets a character (ASCII translation in AL)
int 3
mov bl,al 
mov dl,al 
mov ah,02h ; function 02h - display character
int 21h ; call DOS service

mov ah,09h
mov dx, offset enterbutton
int 21h

mov ah, 09h
mov dx, offset msg1 ; output second message
int 21h
jmp covertHowMany ; converting number that we entered

next:
xor si,si
mov si, ax ; number that we entered now is in si
xor cx,cx 
mov cx,0 ;cx=0

enterfirstnumber: ;entering first number (example 123, first number is 1)
xor ah,ah 
int 16h ; int 16h gets a one character 
int 3
mov bl,al 
mov dl,al 
mov ah,02h ; function 02h - display character
int 21h ; 
jmp convertnumber ; converting this number

input: ;converting number from ascii char to ascii integer
mov ax,bx
mov dx,10
mul dx ; ax:=ax*10
mov bx,ax ; number that I try to convert is in bx now
xor ah,ah 
int 16h ; int 16h gets a character (ASCII translation in AL)
int 3
mov bl,al 
mov dl,al 
mov ah,02h ; function 02h - display character
int 21h 
jmp convertnumber

convertHowMany:
sub al,30h ; convert from ascii character to ascii number
jmp next

convertnumber:
sub al,30h
add bx,ax
inc cx
cmp cx, si
jne input
jmp ending

ending:
mov ax,04C00h
int 21h

end start
```

Comment: Highly recommend you learn how to use the debugger, so that you can find the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least two problems with your code:

The first is that when you reach `convertHowMany` you assume that `AL` still contains the character that the user typed in. That will not be the case, since both [`INT 21h/AH=02h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm) and [`INT 21h/AH=09h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm) modify `AL`. You'll have to save and restore the value of `AL` somehow (e.g. by pushing and popping `AX`).

The second problem is how you initialize `SI` before the loop. You're moving the value of `AX` into `SI`, which means *both* `AL` and `AH`. `AH` is not zero at that point, because you've just used `INT 21h/AH=09h`.
You could change the sequence `xor si,si` / `mov si,ax` into something like `mov si,ax` / `and si,0FFh`.